# curl_setopt working fine in browser but not in cron tab

Tags: php, curl, cron

Cron command - wget --spider 'url'

php file-

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{

$ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); //set  useragent

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error

       return @curl_exec($ch);

}
```

error-
Remote file exists and could contain further links, but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.

not getting where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing `'$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]'` on line 6, but when executing from a crontab, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] is not defined.  Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if an array item exists.

---

```
<?php
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{

       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] : "PHP/5.5")); //set  useragent

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error

       return @curl_exec($ch);

}
```

Comment: same error - Remote file exists and could contain further links, but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.

Comment: I am using godaddy server. Is it possible that they have denied to get data from url through cron jobs?

Comment: now its working, i changed the http_user_agent to isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] : "PHP/5.5" and i changed my cron command to /usr/local/bin/php -q 'filepath'. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you run into an issues in the future. - Trick